# I cannot add a role to any one with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so my code looks like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def admin(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send("hellooooooo")
    guild = ctx.guild
    await guild.create_role(name="role name")
    await user.add_roles(guild)
```

but the role is created but it fails to give the role to the person

Comment: You're not adding a role, you're adding a guild... Haven't you coded that yourself? It doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing here is trying to add the role `guild` to the member. The problem is that `guild` is not a role at all, but the whole server.

You must add the newly created role, the one that is returned by `guild.create_role(name="role name")`.

Here's how to do it :

```py
@bot.command()
async def create_and_add_role(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    guild = ctx.guild
    role = await guild.create_role(name="New role")
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send("Role created and added!")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Some code

Something like this should work:

```
@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def CreateAddRole(ctx, User:discord.Member, RoleName:str):
      await ctx.message.delete()
      role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name = RoleName)
      await User.add_roles(role)
      await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = "NEW ROLE", description = f"{ctx.message.author.mention} created the role {role.mention} and assigned it to {User.mention}", color = discord.Color.green())
```

Try running the code above, because the embed seems more professional than a simple message.